# Error al presionar un boton en android studio(el boton es para login(iniciar sesion) o register(registrarse) con firebase)

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase, firebase-auth

me sale estos errores y no se como solucionarlos:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
> com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,
> java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
> at com.company.nameapp.LoginActivity.lambda$onCreate$1$LoginActivity(LoginActivity.java:37)
> at com.company.nameapp.-$$Lambda$LoginActivity$0hRFztjuxKP0C2xdkqRUcT2XbSE.onClick(lambda)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
> at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

a continuación la linea 37 de `LoginActivity.java`(todo parece estar bien)
`auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailTxt,passwordText).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {`

Answer (score 1):

El error como comentas se produce en esta linea:

```
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailTxt,passwordText)....
```

el problema del NullPointerException al llamar el método `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` se debe a que previamente debes inicializar instanciando `Firebase`, lo debes realizar de esta forma:

```
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```